# Media Queries and Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web, frontend, media-player

I am new to front end development and recently came across media queries and how they work.
I learnt bootstrap prior to media queries and now I am wondering is media query necessary? I feel Bootstrap does the same thing when you create grids and mention the column class name i.e col-2-sm xs, lg etc and gives the responsive feel. Could somebody please guide when what must be used?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is a CSS framework, if you want to use it, you'll have to learn it. Or write your own queries.
And btw, it's `col-sm-2` meaning if the screen width is small(≥576px), it should give the div the width of two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Media queries and Bootstrap are two different approaches. you can use bootstrap to make responsive web design without any knowledge about media query because bootstrap has grid system which allow you to make RWD but you can learn media query to make your own grid system or make some change on any size you want

**to read and learn about Media Query :**

https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

**Bootstrap 4 Grid System :**

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#

**Bootstrap 4 Grid System :**

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/